# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am writing this code below.

```
fileName = input("Enter the file name: ")
InputFile = open(fileName, 'r')
text=InputFile.readable()

sentences = text.count('.') + text.count('?') + \
            text.count(':') + text.count(';') + \
            text.count('!')
```

I can't get past the count function because of this error below. I have done some research and tried importing some libraries but that didn't work. Can someone guide me in the right direction? I feel so lost.

```
 text.count(':') + text.count(';') + \
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Comment: What do you think `text=InputFile.readable()` is doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a buggy line in your code:

```
text = InputFile.readable()
```

Which returns a `boolean` that has no attribute `count`

Should have been:

```
text = InputFile.read()
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you one more question? In this line of code what is the "\" symbol if "/" is division? index = 206.835 - 1.015 * (words / sentences) - \
    84.6 * (syllables / words)

Comment: yes. Is this an operator that allows you put the rest of the code on another line?